# How can I minimize a time value given by a graph depending on a cost value given by another graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Consider a company that wants to lunch a new subsidiary. To do so, four phases are needed: A, B, C, D which have to be done in this order. The length of each depends on how much money is invested in the phase.

Assume that numbers the close to the red edges are for all red ones, and likewise for the purple ones.

[image: Graph in months]

Here is the graph labelled with time.

[image: Graph in €]

Here is the graph labelled with cost in M€.

Considering that we want to realize A and B spending at most €5M, what minimal length of time do we have to foresee? **What path with cost1<5 minimizes cost2 (the time value)?**

How can I handle this problem? Do I have to apply Bellman's algorithm without considering A prioritaire to B prioritaire, which costs €6M? I do not know what critical graphs are.

Do I first have to do a Bellman aglorithm for A and B on time knowing that I must not make my company pay more than 5M? And then A second algorithm from B prioritaire or B rapide, find all values I found and choose the fastest?

But I think that using two algorithms lead me to have several solutions.

I'm not asking for the whole solution, some hints would be really appreciated! ;)

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What do you mean by "what minimal length do we have to foresee?"  I'm not sure what you mean by allowed; of course anything is allowed if it gives you the right answer.  However in this case I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to achieve, what approach you are asking about, and what specifically you are uncertain about.  Why wouldn't you consider A prioritaire to B prioritare?  Why would you omit some edges?  Note that you haven't shown the lengths of some edges, which you might want to fix.

Comment: Do you know about critical paths?

Comment: @D.W. I believe the question is, "What path with $cost_1<5$ minimizes $cost_2$?"